# Python Django db transaction uses update

Tags: python, django, database, transactions

I am using django transactions to work with my DB. The thing I am stuck on is that I have a DB and I want to replace the whole DB table with a new one created in the transaction block. The behavior of `@transaction.atomic` is that it will always update the DB table. So the old table entries will stay there. How to always remove the old entries? Am I missing something in the Django specs? Or do I need to clear the db table manually inside the transaction block?

Comment: Question is not clear, what do you mean by "replace the whole DB"? Can you share code samples to help us understand what you are trying to do?

Comment: updated, instead of "whole db" should be "whole db table"

Comment: Your question is very unclear. An atomic database  transaction is bound by the ACID (atomicity, consistency, isolation, durability) protocol. It means that once a transation starts, it all finishes or it fails. SHould it fail the database will incur a rollback and data is safe. Rethink your question.

Comment: what solution would you recommend then? I have a db table and i need to replace the db table with new data every 10 minutes.

Comment: What holds you from deleting all records and inserting new ones? Not quite understand what the problem is. Maybe if you post some code sample it would become more clear for everybody, even yourself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved - I deleted the table records in the transaction block.
It was a bug in the code.
Thanks for helpful comments